# How to configure kubectl with cluster information from a .conf file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have an admin.conf file containing info about a cluster, so that the following command works fine:

```
kubectl --kubeconfig ./admin.conf get nodes
```

How can I `config` kubectl to use the cluster, user and authentication from this file as default in one command? I only see separate set-cluster, set-credentials, set-context, use-context etc. I want to get the same output when I simply run:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here are the official documentation for how to configure kubectl

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

You have a few options, specifically to this question, you can just copy your `admin.conf` to `~/.kube/config`

Comment: Rather than overwriting whatever data is already in .kube/config, you could do `export KUBECONFIG=path/to/admin.conf`

Comment: Is there a way to use/load multiple config files and have them show up with `kubectl config get-contexts`, and still allow changing contexts with `kubectl config use-context <context-name>`?

Comment: I am using go-client to connect with the cluster. Is there a way to use this config file with the go-client to authenticate the cluster?

Comment: I have install the kubectl on mac using home brew but not been able to find configuration at ~/.kube/config

Comment: Make sure config file is named **config** with NO extensions.

config.conf or config.yaml won't work

Comment: @gunit This is possible: `export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:~/.kube/cluster0:~/.kube/cluster1:~/.kube/cluster3` and: `kubectl config use-context  cluster0`

Answer (score 75):

The best way I've found was to use an environment variable:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/admin.conf
```

Comment: sure but if there are multiple clusters in one config file how do you switch between clusters given that one file?

Comment: @AlexanderMills one file can handle several contexts.

Answer (score 39):

I just alias the kubectl command into separate ones for my dev and production environments via .bashrc

```
alias k8='kubectl'
alias k8prd='kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/config_prd.conf'
```

I prefer this method as it requires me to define the environment for each command.. whereas using an environment variable could potentially lead you to running a command within the wrong environment

Comment: Also would like to note that when using tokens as authentication, the username actually resides within the token, so the name is actually just a reference. So you can name this anything, and reference it appropriately within the context. That is if you want to use one config file and swap contexts each time.

Comment: alias does not persist after git bash restart...

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov you'll need to place it into your ~/.bashrc file assuming bash usage.

Answer (score 24):

> Before answers have been very solid and informative, I will try to add
>   my 2 cents here

### Configure `kubeconfig` file knowing its precedence

If you’re using `kubectl`, here’s the preference that takes effect while determining which **kubeconfig** file is used.

1. use `--kubeconfig` flag, if specified
2. use `KUBECONFIG` environment variable, if specified
3. use `$HOME/.kube/config` file

With this, you can easily override **kubeconfig** file you use per the `kubectl` command:

```sh
#
# using --kubeconfig flag
#
kubectl get pods --kubeconfig=file1
kubectl get pods --kubeconfig=file2

#
# or 
# using `KUBECONFIG` environment variable
#
KUBECONFIG=file1 kubectl get pods
KUBECONFIG=file2 kubectl get pods

#
# or 
# merging your kubeconfig file w/ $HOME/.kube/config (w/ cp backup)
#
cp $HOME/.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config.backup.$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S)
KUBECONFIG= $HOME/.kube/config:file2:file3 kubectl config view --merge --flatten > \
~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig && mv ~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
```

**NOTE:** The `--minify` flag allows us to extract only info about that context, and the `--flatten` flag allows us to keep the credentials unredacted.

#### For your example

```sh
kubectl get pods --kubeconfig=/path/to/admin.conf

#
# or:
#
KUBECONFIG=/path/to/admin.conf kubectl get pods

#
# or: 
#
cp $HOME/.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config.backup.$(date)
KUBECONFIG= $HOME/.kube/config:/path/to/admin.conf kubectl config view --merge --flatten > \
~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig && mv ~/.kube/merged_kubeconfig ~/.kube/config
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-1
kubectl get pods --context=cluster-2
```

Although this precedence list not officially specified in the documentation it is [codified here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/e478dd3a68a8ebf260beb7b9522bcc87cf4c971f/tools/clientcmd/loader.go#L137). If you’re developing client tools for Kubernetes, you should consider using [cli-runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes/cli-runtime) library which will bring the standard `--kubeconfig` flag and `$KUBECONFIG` detection to your program.

**ref article:** https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/

Comment: Just want to add: cluster names in both configs must be different (not both "default") before to use `kubectl config view --merge`.

Answer (score 11):

I name all cluster configs as `.kubeconfig` and this lives in project directory.

Then in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` I have the following export:

```
export KUBECONFIG=.kubeconfig:$HOME/.kube/config
```

This way when I'm in the project directory `kubectl` will load local `.kubeconfig`.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 8):

`kubectl` uses `~/.kube/config` as the default configuration file. So you could just copy your `admin.conf` over it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, even kodekloud recommends doing it, just use mv command

Answer (score 3):

Because there is no built-in `kubectl config merge` command at the moment (follow [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46381)) you can add this function to your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`):

```
function kmerge() {
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
   then
     echo "Please pass the location of the kubeconfig you wish to merge"
  fi
  KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:$1 kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/mergedkub && mv ~/.kube/mergedkub ~/.kube/config
}
```

Then **you can just run from termial**:

`kmerge /path/to/admin.conf`

**and the config file will be merged to `~/.kube/config`**.

You can now switch to the new context with:

```
kubectl config use-context <new-context-name>
```

Or if you're using [kubectx](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) (recommended) you can run: `kubectx <new-context-name>`.

---

(The `kmerge` function is based on @MichaelSp answer at this [post](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/46381#issuecomment-461404505)).

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes keeps the path to search for config files in `$KUBECONFIG`

If you want to add [one more config path](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#append-home-kube-config-to-your-kubeconfig-environment-variable) on top of the existing KUBECONFIG without overriding it (and keeping `~/.kube/config` as the default path to search).

Just run the following each time you want to add a conf file to the KUBECONFIG path

```sh
export KUBECONFIG=${KUBECONFIG:-~/.kube/config}:/path/to/admin.conf
```

You can check it worked by listing the available contexts

```sh
kubectl config get-contexts
```

Then select the one you want to use

```sh
kubectl config use-context <context-name>
```

Comment: There should be a command ```kubectl config set -f``` this is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Manage your config files proper,place below in your profile file, source the .profile / .bash_profile

> ```
> for kconfig in $HOME/.kube/config $(find $HOME/.kube/ -iname "*.config")
> do
>          if [ -f "$kconfig" ];then
>                  export KUBECONFIG=$KUBECONFIG:$kconfig
>          fi
>  done
> ```

switch the contexts from kubectl

Answer (score 0):

When you type `kubectl` I guess you prefer to know which cluster you are pointing. Maybe it's worth creating an alias for that?

```
alias kube-mycluster='kubectl --kubeconfig ~/.kube/mycluster.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible:

```
export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:~/.kube/cluster0:~/.kube/cluster1:~/.kube/cluster3
```

and:

```
kubectl config use-context  cluster0
```